# JCL - Incluir sortin en un fichero

Tags: cobol

Quisiera saber cómo incluir en un paso de `SORT` un fichero que a su vez contiene la ficha `sortin`, es decir el contenido del fichero se ha creado dinámicamente y tiene esta pinta:

```
//SORTIN   DD DSN=DES.LQHISE03.ENTRADA,   
//            DISP=SHR
```

Comment: Bienvenido NatBI a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta amigo, podrías dar un poco mas de info? gracias! saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No se si este paso te servirá, tiene de entrada un sortin y es un paso de sort. Seria el paso siguiente a seguir después de la creación para que te ordene según necesites.

```
PASORT01 EXEC SORTD                                                   
//SORTIN   DD DSN=DES.LQHISE03.ENTRADA,DISP=OLD
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=XX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX,
//            DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
//            SPACE=(TRK,(5,5),RLSE),                                   
//            DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=0,DSORG=PS)                
//SORTWK01 DD SPACE=(CYL,10)                                           
//SORTWK02 DD SPACE=(CYL,10)                                            
//SORTWK03 DD SPACE=(CYL,10)                                            
//SYSIN    DD *                                                         
  SORT FIELDS=(n,n,A),FORMAT=BI                                         
  RECORD LENGTH=(nn),TYPE=F
```